# How to aggregate multiple polygons opencv

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have 2 polygons for 1 image. One is always inside another. How can I choose third polygon, which will be something between big and small polygon?
I try to aggregate labels from 2 different people. Big polygon is union of 2 labels, small polygon inside is intersection of 2 labels.

Comment: Can you share some images?

Comment: if polygons have the same number of points and they are in similar places then you could calculate middle points using `(x1+x2)/2, (y1+y2)/2`